# How to set nativeProps inside of a react array -- React Native

Tags: arrays, animation, react-native, ref, jsx

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to create an array of Animated.View elements that are moved by setting nativeProps. I've chosen to do this for speed reasons.

**The problem**

While placing components with nativeProp refs directly in the render method poses no problems, refs are not recognized if they are in an array.

**Example**

```
componentWillMount: function() {

    this.arrayOfElements = [];

    this.exampleView1.nativeProps = (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void });
    this.exampleView2.nativeProps = (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void });

    var key1 = "Example View 1"
    var key2 = "Example View 2"

    this.arrayOfElements.push(
        <Animated.View key={key1} ref={(nativeProps) => { this.exampleView1.nativeProps = nativeProps }} >
            <Shape />
        </Animated.View>
    );

    this.arrayOfElements.push(
        <Animated.View key={key2} ref={(nativeProps) => { this.exampleView2.nativeProps = nativeProps }} >
            <Shape />
        </Animated.View>
    );
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this.exampleView1.nativeProps); // null --> Means the component was *not* mounted
    console.log(this.exampleView2.nativeProps); // void function --> Means the component was mounted
},

render: function() {
    <View>
        {this.arrayOfElements}
    </View>
},
```

I don't have enough experience in JSX to understand why this is, but its important that I create a JSX loop with refs that allow me to set nativeProps. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why the original problem happens, but refs can be loaded correctly using the map method. As an example:

```
render: function() {
    var arrayOfRefs = ['exampleView1', 'exampleView2'];
    return(
        <View>
            {this.arrayOfRefs.map((name, index) => (
                <Animated.View key={name} ref={(nativeProps) => { this[name].nativeProps = nativeProps }} >
                    <Shape />
                </Animated.View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
```

},